# Docker MySQL: create new user

Tags: php, mysql, docker, virtual-machine

In the [mysql docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) there's a reference on how to create users with:

```
MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

But how can you specify those parameters on the docker-compose.yml file?

So far I have:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: R00t+
```

Another question; how can I connect to the mysql host from outside the container? Inside the container I can connect using:

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'R00t+';
$server = 'mysql';

$dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$server", $user, $pass );
```

Comment: This thread is worth reading https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/213

Comment: I switched to Vagrant and Ansible for provisioning my machine: Docker has issues with Windows (which I have to use)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

About password you are setting all parameters exactly the same as you set root password which is:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: R00t+
    MYSQL_USER: youruser
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: yourpassword
```

To connect with mysql outside container just as host use `localhost` because you redirect ports from container to host machine in this line `- "3306:3306"`

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'R00t+';
$server = 'localhost';

$dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$server", $user, $pass );
```

I assume you are running it on your laptop where you have docker containers started.